# kario control api создание пользователя

Tags: python, api, python-3.6

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, который бы создавал пользователя в kerio control, но по [официальной документации](https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/api/control/reference/interfacewebadmin_1_1_users.html#a717147e59560232e15a071077e62b1b7) не очень получается.

Так в документации написано:

```
void webadmin::Users::create    (   out kerio::web::ErrorList   errors,
out kerio::web::CreateResultList    result,
in UserList     users,
in kerio::web::KId  domainId 
)
```

Вот код скрипта.

```
session = callMethod("Session.login", {"userName": username, "password": password,
                                       "application": {"vendor": "Kerio", "name": "Control Api Demo",
                                                       "version": "9.2.6"}})
token = session["result"]["token"]

create_user = {'credentials': {
        "userName": "Vasia",
        "password": "SecretPassword",
        "passwordChanged": False}}

userslist = [create_user,]
print(userslist)
sessions = callMethod("Users.create", {"users": {"UserList": userslist}, "domainId": "local"}, token)

print(session["result"])
```

session это вход в API, токен получаем, дальше создаю массив 'credentials' в котрый помещаю все поля для создания пользователя.
в конце принт выдает токен, в место ид пользователя, ну и в системе он не появляется.

Списко пользователей могу забрать, данные по конектам и пр, а создать юзера неполучается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий код:

```
users = callMethod("Users.create", {"users": [{"credentials": {"userName": text[0], "password": "", "passwordChanged": False}, "fullName": text[1].replace(",", " "), "description": text[2].replace(",", " "),
                      "autoLogin":{"macAddresses":{"enabled":False,"value":[]},"addresses":{"enabled":True,"value":[text[3].replace(",", ".")]}}, "groups":[{"id":groupid,"name":text[4].replace(",", " "),"isGroup":True,"domainName":""}]
                      }], "domainId": "local"}, token)
```

Вместо `text[i]` подставте ваши значения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)